# Kotlin extensions unresolved references

Tags: android, kotlin

i stated to learn kotlin and tried to create a project by kotlin guides. In one of the guides said that i can use View's ids instead `findViewById`. I have imported `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin, added it in gradle file^ but still can't get object's reference by using only id. Can someone help me? I'm using Android Studio 2.3 and Kotlin version 1.1.2-5. Here's my code:

> Main gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.1.2-5"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

    }
}
```

> App gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ".kotlintodoapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.pawegio.kandroid:kandroid:0.5.0@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    a:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    a:layout_width="match_parent"
    a:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        a:id="@+id/simpleRecyclerView"
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

> ActivityMain.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        simpleRecyclerView.setFixedSize(true)
    }
}
```

Android studio says that `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*` is unused import, and tries to import `simpleRecyclerView` as id.

Comment: @zsmb13 yes, i installed kotlin plugins, and it works nice until i reboot android studio. Is it studio error maybe?

Comment: Did you try to clean or rebuild project?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add the kotlin-android-extensions dependency in your top level gradle file.

project gradle config:

```
dependencies {
   …
   classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

app gradle config:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

This configuration should make your project work like you expect. Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: Then you have another problem, this is from the official kotlin docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html